# How do I create a GUI Calculator in Java?

Tags: java

I am creating a Calculator GUI in java. So far I have created a layout and added everything to the canvas. I am now in the implementing phase. My current problem is that when I can not enter more than one-digit numbers. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tbsu.jpg)

Comment: `.setText()` replaces the text wholesale. How do you suppose you would _add to the end_ of the text?

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Answer (score 0):

at numberbox.setText, instead of setting new value each time on button click, get existing value and append new value. 
old value = numberbox.getText;
numberbox.setText(oldvalue+new value);

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = numberBox.getText();
//Your Code Here
text += actionPerformed(e);
numberBox.setText(text);
```

You should try update text.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a simple calculator would have the characters they would like displayed within the Number Box as the actual caption on the button selected. This then means that all you need to **append** to the Number Box is the caption of the button selected. Knowing this greatly reduces the code contained within the **actionPerformed** event.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    numberBox.setText(numberBox.getText() + ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText());
}
```

And that's all.